# What is the themeResource for window's title text color?

Tags: c#, uwp

This title bar text color changes between black and white depending on currently selected system color (white text on darker backgrounds and black text on lighter backgrounds)

[image]

What is the `ThemeResource` for that color?

I have a button with a `background` set to `SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush` and I would like to have this effect of adjusting `foreground` (font color) depending on currently selected accent.

---

I tried `SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush` but it seems like this and `SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush` are the same colors (and I hadn't changed anything in system settings).

Comment: This can't be both WPF and UWP

Answer (score 2):

There is not a single brush that will do the trick.

> Avoid using the accent color as a background, especially for text and icons. Because the accent color can change, if you must use it as a background, there’s some additional work you must do to ensure that foreground text is easy to read. (Source: [UWP Style Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/color))

Building on the example algorithm they propose using in the documentation, this should do the trick:

```
private void UpdateAccentColorForeground(FrameworkElement element)
{
    var uiSettings = new UISettings();
    Color c = uiSettings.GetColorValue(UIColorType.Accent);

    element.RequestedTheme = ((5 * c.G + 2 * c.R + c.B) <= 8 * 128)
        ? ElementTheme.Light
        : ElementTheme.Dark;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is `SystemColorWindowTextColor`. This will link to the current system foreground color for text.

You can find a complete list on the [MSDN site here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources)

Comment: That specific color is used for the HighContrast theme. You should not mess with that color, as it can have a huge negative effect for users who have various accessibility needs.

Comment: @DavidGrochocki I think you're misunderstanding the question. He's talking about overriding that color. If you override the color it doesn't matter what it's set to by the user. This is not a bad practice. It's done often to brand style applications for businesses.

Comment: "There's a set of color values derived from the Windows system palette... many of the XAML Brush resources consume these colors when the system is operating (and the app is running) using the "HighContrast" theme... The keys follow the naming format: `SystemColor[name]Color`." SystemColorWindowTextColor is one of those color values, and it is only applicable in the "HighContrast" theme, so it should not be overwritten. (Source: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources))

Comment: @DavidGrochocki the OP didn't ask what Microsoft Guidelines were. The OP asked how to change it using a key. If Microsoft intended no one to override it they shouldn't have exposed it.

Comment: It is not a matter of following guidelines or not. Your proposal simply wont work (I just tried it). OP would like to "[adjust] foreground (font color) depending on currently selected accent." OP _tried_ to do this by trying to override a key. If you want an accent-aware foreground color (i.e. light text on a dark accent color and dark text on a light accent color), it is not possible to do this with a single color definition. And even if it was, it would not be by overwriting a color that _only_ affects users that use the HighContrast theme.